# Document Upload in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, document

I am writing Windows Phone 8.1 app, I want to Upload documents in my app. How to upload document those are in my windows phone documents library? I read somewhere about this:

```
"KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary"
```

But do not much about it. How to solve this?

Comment: Where do you want to upload ?To your server?What is the file type?

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi Yes, I want to return through web service to server!! Thank you brpther. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

> **You can't use the Documents library in a Windows Phone Store app.**

1. You can't publish a Windows Phone Store app that specifies the
   documentsLibrary capability to the Windows Phone Store. The Store
   blocks the publishing of the app.
2. Your app can't access the Documents library in the phone's internal storage. If another app creates a Documents folder on the
   optional SD card, however, your app can see that folder.

Source - msdn documentation

To access SD card contents

```
using Windows.Storage;

...

            // Get the logical root folder for all external storage devices.
            StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;

            // Get the first child folder, which represents the SD card.
            StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

            if (sdCard != null)
            {
                // An SD card is present and the sdCard variable now contains a reference to it.
            }
            else
            {
                // No SD card is present.
            }
```

Once you access it Use GetFilesAsync (CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery) and GetFoldersAsync (CommonFolderQuery.DefaultQuery) to get the contents of the SD card efficiently.

Comment: OK, thanks, then is it possible to upload documents thorugh SD card? If yes, then explain me.

Comment: @NiteshKothari have updated my post, after selecting the files , you can upload them